# How to power an RPi Model 1A with my Mac?

Tags: power-supply, usb-power

I have a MacBook Pro and a Raspberry Pi 1 Model A. I'm just trying to power the RPi (I need a power source). I've searched hi and low, and the best/easiest solution seems to be finding a USB A male-to-male data cable and plug it into both my laptop and my RPi.

However these cables are extremely rare and none of the stores in my area (RadioShack, Staples, BestBuy, etc.) carry them.

I'm trying to find a solution that will work *today*, so, using standard (easy to find in brick and mortar stores!) cables. I don't really have the time to order something online and wait for it to be shipped to me.

So I ask: what is the easiest & quickest way I can provide my RPi with power?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pi A has a micro usb cable for charging, just use any micro usb b type to power it, using the pwr in port.

Comment: This will **NOT** work! The Mac has proper standards compliant USB ports, and will only supply 100mA unless higher current is negotiated which is **NOT POSSIBLE** as the Pi does not have data lines in the power connector. (It is possible that the Pi MAY run on 100mA, but this would NOT be reliable.)